# The distance between any two pages in Google Analytics

Tags: google-analytics

With a Funnel you can determine whether users navigated a certain path to some destination page.  Is there a way to determine if users ever got from page A to page B regardless of which and how many pages they hit in between?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well you could setup a profile that filters all other pages besides A and B out, therefore the profile only reports on page A and page B, then you would be able to see if traffic that saw page A, later saw page B.

If you want do a little js programming, then you could also use a custom variable, set it to 1 when a visitor sees page A, then set it to 2 if a visitor sees page A and they had the custom variable set to 1 already.

Comment: Good idea!  The custom variable solution seems like a great way to go.

Comment: The only issue I see with the custom variables is that you are using up a slot just to determine the distance between two pages.  If you had many pages you wanted to do this with, it wouldn't work.

Comment: "If you had many pages you wanted to do this with, it wouldn't work."

Yes that is correct, the same is true for the profile method, as the number of profiles you have is also limited I believe.

Another method would be to create your own cookie to track a view of page A, then if the user makes it to page B and has the cookie, then track an event or a virtual pageview, this mthod is basically unlimited. You could also use webstorage http://www.w3.org/TR/webstorage/ instead of a cookie if it is available.

Answer (score 0):

An advanced segment would tell you this:

Include visits that saw page A AND page B, you'll get a subset of visits and can compare their behavior, performance, etc... to the rest of the visits.

No programming, dynamic and applies to past data.